# Understanding getchar() and putchar() in C

Tags: c

`getchar()` function reads a character from the screen and returns it's ASCII value. This function reads only single character at a time.

`putchar()` function puts the passed character on the screen and returns the ASCII value of the character. This function puts only single character at a time.

Now consider `Code 1` below

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int c=getchar();
    putchar(c);
}
```

Output:

> abcd
>
> a

Now consider `Code 2`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int c=getchar();
    while(c!=EOF)
    {
        putchar(c);
        c=getchar();
    }
}
```

Output:

> a
>
> a
>
> abcd
>
> abcd
>
> ^Z

`Code 1` is working fine as, If we type more than 1 character then `getchar()` function will only reads the first character and return its `ASCII` value. But in case of `Code 2` with loop, Why the whole string is getting printed instead of 1 character?

Comment: @alk *why the whole string is getting printed instead of 1 character*

Comment: OT: It's `int main(void)` at least.

Comment: Is your question about getchar and putchar or is it about a loop? By your description it seems you are understanding what is happening except that in Code 2 you have a loop

Comment: What do you ***not*** understand about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Code 2, when you type in a string, say `"abcd"`and press the enter key, the data entered gets into the standard input stream(`stdin`)<sup>1</sup>. `getchar()` reads a character from the `stdin` and then, the execution of the program reaches the `while` loop.

In the loop,`putchar` outputs the character stored in `c`, the first character which you entered, which is `a`. The next call to `getchar` does not wait for further input as it saw characters in the `stdin`<sup>2</sup>. This `getchar` reads the next character, `b` and since it is not `EOF`, the loop continues.

This process continues until `getchar` reads an `EOF` character(which you input using `CTRL+Z`) and finally, the program ends.

<sup>1</sup>: All data includes the enter key which you press.
<sup>2</sup>: This also means that `getchar` waits for you to input a character when the `stdin` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

This is known as "line discipline" "icanon".

To make a long story short:
Input from terminals is handled "by line". NOTHING is passed to your program until You hit "Return".
This makes possible to edit the line (erase last char and overtype it) in case of error. This is handled by kernel before getchar (which is usually implemented as a macro) can see it.

Similarly output is buffered inside libc and only actually sent to kernel when a "Newline" ('\n') char is seen (unless You explicitly flush()). Note this differs from above because it is handled by libc, while input is handled by kernel.

If You want to process input characters one at a time, right after they are typed You must set the line discipline of the specific terminal used to "cbreak". This is what many terminal handling libraries do (e.g.: ncurses).

Have a look to the man page for stty (1) for some discussion.

Back to Your snippet:
what happens there is all chars are buffered in kernel (and correctly echoed in the first line) until You hit "CR".
At that point the whole line is passed to your program which happily loops eating chars and spitting them back.
When the "cr" is reached (libc actually converts it to "LineFeed" '\n') the whole line You built one char at a time is spit back to kernel and hence to terminal.
You are then hitting "CTRL-Z", which is interpreted *by kernel* as EOF and, as such returned via libc (a further getchar() would fail and return -1).
If You want to be able to read ALL chars (including Ctrl-Z on Win, thar would be CTRL-D under Unix/Linux) you need to set the line discipline to "raw" (a very advanced feature likely to lock your terminal ;).

Answer (score 0):

- Code snippet 1 reads a (unsigned) character, prints it and ends the program.
- Code snippet 2 reads a (unsigned) characters, if it did not read `EOF` (typically -1) the characters is printed and another (unsigned) character is read and the program starts over with printing it. Else if `EOF` had been read instead the program ends.